# Passing an error from one async function to another

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a convoluted system, which totally works on async/await. What I want is to handle multiple types of errors from an async function in one and only try/catch block. Which means that I call this function from another async function.
But the concept of handling exceptions in a parent async function seems to fail. In the below example what I get - is just a warning about unhandled promise rejection, and the catch block in the parent won't ever get an error. I've tried this also with simply throwing and error, but unsuccessfully either.

```
const die = (word) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(word));

const live = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));

const daughterAsync = async () => {
    await live();
    try {
        await die('bye');
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    try {
        await die('have a beatiful time');
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    await live();
};

const parentAsync = async () => {
    try {
        daughterAsync();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error catched'); // never happens
        console.log(err);
    }
};

parentAsync();
```

I have a feeling that I don't get something about async functions to perform such a stunt

Comment: As a note: in an `async` function you do not need to write `return Promise.reject(err);` you could just write `throw err`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `daughterAsync();` line only starts the promise running, but it doesn't save the reference to it or wait for it to resolve. You need to `await` the promise returned by `daughterAsync` inside of `parentAsync`'s `try` block in order to `catch` errors in `daughterAsync`:

```js
const die = (word) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(word));

const live = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));

const daughterAsync = async () => {
    await live();
    try {
        await die('bye');
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    try {
        await die('have a beatiful time');
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    await live();
};

const parentAsync = async () => {
    try {
        await daughterAsync();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error catched');
        console.log(err);
    }
};

parentAsync();
```